# increase root partition size

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

I created an ec2 instance and set the root device to 120GB but only 20GB shows up in the parition:

```
[root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ec2-user]# lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0    1G  0 disk
ââxvda1 202:1    0  949M  0 part
xvdb    202:16   0  120G  0 disk
ââxvdb1 202:17   0   20G  0 part /
```

How do I add the remaining 100GB to the / partition?

Comment: Would seem this should be a simple thing to do, but warning: uou are about to enter into the AWS hell of 1000 cuts.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-expand-volume.html

Comment: Can you just do `resize2fs /dev/xvdb`?

Comment: tried the resize2fs but got this error: `resize2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
resize2fs: Device or resource busy while trying to open /dev/xvdb
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.`

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of tutorials covering this, but general gist is:

- you need to detach the volume from the instance (requires bringing it down)
- Mount the volume to another running Ec2 instance (not as its root partion)
- Resize it here
- Detach and reattach back to original instance as the root partition
- restart the original instance

Below is another way to do it with snapshots instead of using a second instance:

https://alestic.com/2010/02/ec2-resize-running-ebs-root/

Comment: well...I can't detach the root partition, can I?

Answer (score 0):

To resize partition online without detaching the volume (/root for example) use xfs_growfs instead resize2fs

```
xfs_growfs /dev/xvdb
```

Answer (score 0):

Rescan available disk space

```
echo 1 > /sys/block/sda/device/rescan
```

Grow specific partition

```
growpart /dev/sda 1
```

Reconfigure partition file type

```
resize2fs /dev/sda1
```